# Using .htaccess, How can you strip files and non-existing directorys from the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to limit access to only serve index pages from valid directories.

The following `.htaccess` file partially works, but not as efficiently as it could.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R]
```

Example:

```
example.com/dir1/
example.com/dir2/
example.com/dir2/sub1/
example.com/dir2/sub1/page.html
```

Request `example.com/dir1/` exists, do not redirect.

Request `example.com/dir1/sub1/` doesn't exist, remove `sub1/`

Request `example.com/dir1/page.html` doesn't exist, remove `page.html`

Request `example.com/dir2/sub1/page.html` exists, but still remove `page.html`

Request `example.com/1/2/3/4/5/` doesn't exist, remove `1/2/3/4/5`

The `.htaccess` I have at the moment, redirects after striping out each directory level and so makes several requests to the server. I know of the `RewriteRule` `N` flag that repeats the rule, but trying to use that always results in a `500 internal server error`.

The point of this code is to redirect all requests to the lowest level directory that exists, so that only the index pages are accessible to viewers.

This needs to be dynamic, so any new or existing directory is available.

A strange question, but a viable solution would be very useful I'm sure to many people.

Comment: You're going to be *way* better off writing a short little script and just routing everything through that instead of trying to use htaccess' terrible logic for this.

Comment: I don't think the N flag would be any better than what you have right now, like wise the N rule will make internal requests, but regardless it does not work like what you have it works with the entire URI until it finds a match.